# Why does it appear I have less graphics memory than I expect?

Tags: intel-graphics

I'm using the onboard graphics adapter in my desktop computer running OpenSuSE Leap 15.1 64 bit. In the BIOS I've selected to allocate 1024MB of RAM to the graphics adapter, yet the OS thinks it has 256MB.

Is there any obvious reason for this discrepancy?

```
lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
        Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```